# $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac n{(n_p)!}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, prime-numbers

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac n{(n_p)!}}=? $$

where, $ (n_p)! $ is the product of first $n$ prime numbers.

Any hint or solution would be extremely useful

Comment: "*Where $(n_p)!$ is the product of the first $n$ prime numbers*"... so, compare $(n_p)!$ to $2^n$.  Is one always strictly larger than the other?  What can this observation be used for in regards to the original problem?

Comment: The original question seems too simple. Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}n!/(n_p)!$?

Comment: @CaveJohnson That's also too simple. Both go to 0.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, but at least need some reasoning.

Comment: @CaveJohnson no, the original question is correct. I would be thankful if you answer both :what you mentioned and original one

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you, I understood it

Comment: I'm closing this as no context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In prime number theorem we have a function that have the following property: $$\text{number of primes till x}=\pi(x)\sim \frac x{\log x}$$

Because of that we have that $\frac n{\log n}!\le (n_p)!\le n_p!$

Where $n_p!$ is the product of all the numbers till the $n$-th prime.

Hence $$\frac n{\frac n{\log n}!}\ge \frac n{(n_p)!}\ge \frac n{n_p!}$$

You can show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac n{\frac n{\log n}!}=0$ and that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n_p!}=0$ thus by the squeeze theorem $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac n{(n_p)!}=0$$

---

Edit

I just thought about this and I understood how stupid I was...

Instead of using $\pi(x)$ and get $\frac n{\log n}!\le (n_p)!\le n_p!$ I can just say $n!\le (n_p)!\le n_p!$ and use squeeze theorem on$$\frac n{n!}\ge \frac n{(n_p)!}\ge \frac n{n_p!}$$

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-th prime number
is about $n\ln n$.
This follows from
the prime number theorem.

Therefore,
we have a much stronger result:
if $p_n$ is the
$n$-th prime then
$\dfrac{n}{p_n}
\approx \dfrac{n}{n\ln n}
=\dfrac1{\ln n}
\to 0
$.

In addition,
$\ln n_p!
\approx n$
(one of Chebychev's functions),
so
$n_p! =
e^{n(1+o(1))}
$.

Comment: It's a bit different: the Chebyshev's function that is asymptotic to $n$ is the sum of logarithms of the primes _less than_ $n$, not the first $n$ primes.

Comment: So then $\ln n_p! \approx n \ln n$ is even larger and $n_p! = n^{n(1+o(1))}$.